# appcentre reports: Your iOS app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-authentication

It would seem that the facebook appcentre review team and myself are talking about completely different things in relation to the above alert and allthough I have asked them to explain what they mean by it several times all they reply with is this canned answer:

> Your iOS app does not appear to have Facebook Login integration.
>   Please either implement Facebook Login or remove this integration as a
>   listed platform in the developer app. You can read more here:
>   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk.

In my app I have implemented the code from the "hellofacebooksample" that comes with the facebook SDK. This all works. I can login, I can post, I can logout. When in facebook app on the iPad and I click on the name of my iOS app that appears in a post, the facebook app moves to the background and my app moves to the foreground. To me this looks like facebook login integration, but appearantly the review team refers to something else all together and they seem unable to explain this to me other then sending me the same canned message over and over again. Even though the "share" button is not hard to find I include the following instructions when I submit the app details page for review with the facebook appcentre:

> Make sure you have the latest version of the app: Mandala Magick.
>
> Start the app. If the menus are not showing, reveal the menus by
>   tapping the disclosure button at the bottom (portrait mode) or right
>   (landscape mode). Select the "options" button. From the revealed
>   options select: "Disperse mandala". From the dispersion options
>   select: "Share on Facebook". Here is the Facebook sso integration
>   section. You can login if not already. You can share current mandala
>   on Facebook.

Is it me?

Perhaps someone out there can explain why I keep hitting a brick wall.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here. Be sure to detail as much as you can about how and in which scenarios Facebook is used when you submit you application.